# pdfscreen's panel Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, pdfscreen

I am having trouble understanding how the panel table of contents of the `pdfscreen` package works. The only thing that I got from the documentation was that in an article-type document, the section names will become the default items in the table of contents, and that `\tableofcontents` should not be used in the body. So I did as instructed and created a test presentation from one of the templates online:

```
\documentclass[titlepage]{article}
\usepackage{xspace,colortbl}
\usepackage[screen,panelright,code,sectionbreak,paneltoc,chocolate]{pdfscreen}
 \margins{.5in}{.5in}{.5in}{.5in}
 \screensize{6in}{8in}

\usepackage{amsmath}


\title{\Huge\textbf{My Title}}
\\
author{\Large M. Y. Name \\  
  {Department} \\
  {Organization} }


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.635}
%\maketitle

\begin{screen}
% \margins{.65in}{.65in}{.65in}{.65in}
 \margins{.35in}{.45in}{.35in}{.35in}
 %\screensize{6.25in}{8in}
 \screensize{5.25in}{7in}
 %\changeoverlay
 \paneloverlay{but.pdf}
 %\overlay{logo.pdf}
 \def\pfill{\vskip6pt}
 \definecolor{panelbackground}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.9}
 \backgroundcolor{white}
 \paneloverlayempty
\end{screen}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Overview}
Lorem
\section{Body}
Ipsum
\section{Summary}
Dolor
\end{document}
```

In a normal LaTeX document, the table of contents are updated after compiling twice. However, here I am unable to get the TOC to update after I modify my section headings or such. I do not understand this, as it appears rather ad-hoc (I made some changes, they did not appear after multiple compilations. I removed them, and the earlier sections appeared). Does anyone know what is happening and how to fix this so that I know the most recent table of contents will appear when I am making the presentation?

---

**UPDATE:** Gonzalo's solution works. There is another inelegant way through which i got it to work, though I don't know the exact mechanism. In the body, introduce the `\tableofcontents` and compile (twice). This suppresses anything that the package itself does and you get an updated table of contents. Now remove the TOC and the default `pdfscreen` table of contents takes over, with the updated contents.

Comment: I do not have enough reputation to create it, but I think `pdfscreen` should have a tag of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the auxiliary file `.toc` and compile again (two times).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I don't see a .toc file.

Comment: @yayu: in the same directory where your `.tex` file resides, there should be a file `<your_file_name>.toc`; delete this file before compiling.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I also discovered a crude workaround that I have added to my question for the record.